# connection Spring-Boot to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm new using Spring Boot and I'm having an error connecting it to MySQL Database, I already read all tutorials but still haven't found the problem.

> ERROR 27341 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool
>   : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Could not create connection to database server.
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not
>   get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
>   obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Could not create connection to database server.   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:328)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_predio?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**to run the application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("au.basicexpert.predio.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("au.basicexpert.predio.repository")
@ComponentScan("au.basicexpert.predio.controller")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: 0

Shutdown the local MySQL and run the project again with debug enabled. Please post the full log trace.

Why do you want to use the old version of MySQL connector? Unless if there is a specific reason behind it go for a new version always. if you are not sure what is a latest version remove the version and let maven manages it for the first time.

Comment: Hi Kirby, it works now! I just needed to shutdown the MyQSL. I can't believe that was the only problem, also I actualised the MyQSL connector. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: glad it works for you

Comment: Please give a up vote if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown the local MySQL and run the project again with debug enabled. Please post the full log trace.

Why do you want to use the old version of MySQL connector? Unless if there is a specific reason behind it go for a new version always. if you are not sure what is a latest version remove the version and let maven manages it for the first time.